# Getting error in Sqoop when Import-all-tables in Cloudera Quickstart VM

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I'm getting the following error when I try to import-all-tables via Sqoop:

```
sqoop import-all-tables -m 12 --connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" --username=retail_dba --password=cloudera --warehouse-dir=/r/cloudera/sqoop_import

Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
17/04/23 15:29:27 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.8.0
17/04/23 15:29:27 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
17/04/23 15:29:27 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
17/04/23 15:29:27 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
17/04/23 15:29:27 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `categories` AS t LIMIT 1
17/04/23 15:29:27 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `categories` AS t LIMIT 1
17/04/23 15:29:27 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce
Note: /tmp/sqoop-cloudera/compile/e8e72a2e112fced2b0f3251b5666473d/categories.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
17/04/23 15:29:30 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-cloudera/compile/e8e72a2e112fced2b0f3251b5666473d/categories.jar
17/04/23 15:29:30 WARN manager.MySQLManager: It looks like you are importing from mysql.
17/04/23 15:29:30 WARN manager.MySQLManager: This transfer can be faster! Use the --direct
17/04/23 15:29:30 WARN manager.MySQLManager: option to exercise a MySQL-specific fast path.
17/04/23 15:29:30 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Setting zero DATETIME behavior to convertToNull (mysql)
17/04/23 15:29:30 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of categories
17/04/23 15:29:31 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
17/04/23 15:29:32 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
17/04/23 15:29:32 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at quickstart.cloudera/192.168.40.134:8032
17/04/23 15:29:37 INFO db.DBInputFormat: Using read commited transaction isolation
17/04/23 15:29:37 INFO db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat: BoundingValsQuery: SELECT MIN(`category_id`), MAX(`category_id`) FROM `categories`
17/04/23 15:29:37 INFO db.IntegerSplitter: Split size: 4; Num splits: 12 from: 1 to: 58
17/04/23 15:29:38 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:12
17/04/23 15:29:38 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1492945339848_0010
17/04/23 15:29:39 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1492945339848_0010
17/04/23 15:29:39 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1492945339848_0010/
17/04/23 15:29:39 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1492945339848_0010
17/04/23 15:29:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1492945339848_0010 running in uber mode : false
17/04/23 15:29:52 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
17/04/23 15:29:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1492945339848_0010 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1492945339848_0010 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1492945339848_0010_000002 exited with  exitCode: 1
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1492945339848_0010/Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1492945339848_0010_02_000001
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:578)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:481)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:763)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
17/04/23 15:29:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
17/04/23 15:29:52 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group FileSystemCounters is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter instead
17/04/23 15:29:52 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 19.6175 seconds (0 bytes/sec)
17/04/23 15:29:52 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead
17/04/23 15:29:52 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 0 records.
17/04/23 15:29:52 ERROR tool.ImportAllTablesTool: Error during import: Import job failed!`enter
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like application masters are getting killed repeatedly meaning, they are not getting as much as memory as they would like. If you are just trying out sqoop on cloudera virtual machine, dont use `-m 12`, this will try spawn 12 parallel map tasks which you (single) machine may not be able to handle. Leave off that setting altogether or try with `--direct` instead . Also whats going on with `--warehousedir=/r/cloudera/sqoop_import` ? is `/r/` as typo or it should be `/user/`

Try this instead :

```
sqoop import-all-tables \
--connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" \
--warehouse-dir=/user/cloudera/sqoop_import
--username=retail_dba \
--direct
--password=cloudera;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to load first one table instead import-all-tables, Also try to restrict your mappers while using import-all-tables , 12 mappers is hampering the memory on VM.

```
sqoop import-all-tables \
--connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" \
--warehouse-dir=/user/cloudera/sqoop_import
--username=retail_dba \
--password=cloudera
-m 2
```